# Fourier expansion of absolute value of a periodic function

Tags: analysis, fourier-series, approximation

For an arbitrary periodic function p(x), whose period and
Fourier expansion might have been known in advance, how
can we get the Fourier expansion/coefficients of |p(x)|
from them?

Or, if possible, is there some good polynimial approximation
for absolute function/step function?

Comment: There would be a simple solution for the squared absolute value, but I guess you really need the absolute value without the squares, right?

Comment: I don't believe there is any simple expression for the coefficients of $|p|$ in terms of the coefficients of $p$.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers and kind help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot  get the coefficients of $|f|$ from the coefficients of $f$. Consider that $\sin x$ has a very simple Fourier series (just one nonzero coefficient), but $|\sin x|$ has an infinite series. You can't really get the latter from the former.

This applies generally to nonlinear transformations (other than composition with polynomials, which translates into convolution)

Concerning approximation of $|x|$ by polynomials: this is possible on finite intervals (see [Sequence of functions that converge on absolute value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234582/sequence-of-functions-that-converge-on-absolute-value)) but not uniformly on the entire line. So, if $f$ is unbounded, approximating $|f|$ by $p_n(f)$ is very problematic.

Bernstein polynomials, mentioned in the above thread, give a constructive approximation to $|x|$ on a finite interval. Given the importance of this specific function, there is some research on getting a better approximation for it: see the introduction of [this paper](http://www.math.vanderbilt.edu/~esaff/texts/98.pdf). But in practice, if you want a good low-degree polynomial approximation to $|x|$ on a given interval, use a numerical routine [like this one](http://www.mathworks.com/examples/matlab/7520-best-approximation-with-the-remez-command).

Comment: Thank you, NH, I learned before that absolute value or step function on a finite interval can be approximated by various polynomials, but I did not find any that for the whole real axis, perhaps there is no such thing. I might try to change my problem to a finite interval. Your references are somewhat too mathematical, while what I need is more physical or technical results that can be used directly. But I still appreciate it very much. Thanks.

Comment: The very last reference is to a Matlab script that generates polynomials approximating $|x|$, in case that helps..

Comment: Thank you~~Actually my problem is to solve an equation in which there is some absolute value of periodic function, so I want to first approximate it with some handful polynomial or so, whose Fourier expansion can be available directly, and then solve the unknowns. Maybe this approach is not practical.